# Align multi-columns inside Select Dropdown box

Tags: javascript, jquery, sql, html-select

Hey all I have been trying to find an example of a 3-column dropdown box but have been unsussesful in doing so. Though I have found 2-column ones but they do not seem to work as I need them to.

In the dropdown I'd like it to look like this:

```
Heading1 | Heading 2     | Heading 3
something| something here| Something here again
blah blah| bleblah       | blahblahlbha
hello    | hi            | goodbye
```

I have found a *somewhat* nice jquery code that **tries** to add spaces where its needed in order to align the columns with each other.

```
$.each(responce["TrainingSite"], function (key, value) {
   //Loops to populate the dropdown options
   $('#TrainingSite_1').append($('<option>', {
      value: value.RoomN,
      text: value.RoomN + ' +' + value.RoomC + ' +' + value.RoomCo
   }));
});

$("#TrainingSite_1 option").each(function () {
   var len = $(this).text().length;

   if (len > biggestLength) {
       biggestLength = len;
   }
});

var padLength = biggestLength + spacesToAdd;

$("#TrainingSite_1 option").each(function () {
   var parts = $(this).text().split('+');
   var strLength = parts[0].length;

   for (var x = 0; x < (padLength - strLength) ; x++) {
      parts[0] = parts[0] + ' ';
   }

   $(this).text(parts[0].replace(/ /g, '\u00a0') + parts[1] + parts[2]).text;
});
```

Which produces this result:

[image]

Anyone have code for either side (MS SQL / Jquery) that will do the alignment that I need?

**Working JSFIDDLE example**

https://jsfiddle.net/e17Lt1mL/

Comment: Set three container divs as vars, append whatever content to them for each of your elements and than create a bigger container to include the three. You can have your pick at floating them (box model) or using `flexbox`.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Mind showing a working example of that?

Comment: What you posted doesn't make much sense. You've got some jQuery snippets. Without any working example, or at least some markup. They're completely out of context.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Updated my OP with JSFIDDLE example.

Comment: :) What you want is simply not possible in today's web. `<select>`s and `<option>`s are unstyle-able cross browser in a controllable fashion. Use `<div>`s and `<span>`s, like every library has been when creating dropdowns for the past... 20 years? Bootstrap's dropdowns, Select2, Selectize, ng-select, they all hide the select and use custom, controllable and style-able elements built on the fly to pass data to the select. Roll your own or use one of those.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party here, but you're on the right track with spacing out the column data.  Just add a fixed width font to your select and option elements and it will work.  I use:

select.fw, option.fw {font-family: 'courier new'}